# Hot Chocolate: Using IResolverContext.ReportError and ExecutionEventListener for Excluding Errors from Response Array

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

In the context of hot chocolate, how can I utilize IResolverContext.ReportError and ExecutionEventListener to report an error without including it in the errors array within the response? I attempted to access the middleware context, but it seems that the result object, which I believe holds the errors, is null when encountering a ResolverError.

I've digged through the documentation and source code, however, cannot find anything nor any other examples of this use case.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLYZr.png)

I believe IMiddlewareContext stores the errors under a Result property, however, at the point of ResolverError execution, the property is null.